# Service broker with only domain account

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker

I am new to MS Sql's service broker.

I've examined a couple of tutorials. But I could not find an answer.

I have distributed servers, but luckily all of them are under the same domain.

Is it possible to accomplish a structure without using any certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Do no use dialog security. Make sure all your [`BEGIN DIALOG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187377.aspx) statements use `ENCRYPTION = OFF` clause:

```
BEGIN DIALOG @handle
  FROM SERVICE @from_service   
  TO SERVICE @to_service
  ON CONTRACT @contract
  WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
```

Grant `SEND` permission to `[public]` on each destinations service:

```
GRANT SEND ON SERVICE::<servicename> TO [public];
```

Use `WINDOWS` authentication on `ENDPOINT`s:

```
 CREATE ENDPOINT broker 
   STATE = STARTED
   AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 4022)
   FOR SERVICE_BROKER (AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS);
```

Grant `CONNECT` to ENDPOINT permission to the domain account used by your SQL Service:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::broker TO [domain\sqlserviceaccount];
```

(edited to correct GRANT SEND syntax)

Comment: Remus, for grant permission on CONNECT; I think the domain account must be the account used by my SQL Service. Is there a way to use another domain account?

Answer (score 0):

Remus, could you do this with Encryption but without Master Key Encryption? I see that when I use `AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS`, I can also do `ENCRYPTION = SUPPORTED`.  Reading about SB, there's two types of encryption (transport & message).

This is all on the same internal network, but I'd rather not make the contents of the messages readable.  I think that just means I need transport security - and I have no idea if that requires certificates or master key encryption.

Thanks!